# How to systematically populate a whitelist for a sandboxing program?

Tags: reflection, lua, hook, sandbox, introspection

On pp. 260-263 of *Programming in Lua* (4th ed.), the author discusses how to implement "sandboxing" (i.e. the running of untrusted code) in Lua.

When it comes to imposing limiting the functions that untrusted code can run, he recommends a "whitelist approach":

> We should never think in terms of what functions to remove, but what functions to add.

---

This question is about ***tools and techniques for putting this suggestion into practice.***  (I expect there will be confusion on this point I want to emphasize it upfront.)

---

The author gives the following code as an illustration of a sandbox program based on a whitelist of allowed functions.  (I have added or moved around some comments, and removed some blank lines, but I've copied the executable content verbatim from the book).

```
-- From p. 263 of *Programming in Lua* (4th ed.)
-- Listing 25.6. Using hooks to bar calls to unauthorized functions

local debug = require "debug"
local steplimit = 1000    -- maximum "steps" that can be performed
local count = 0           -- counter for steps

local validfunc = {       -- set of authorized functions
  [string.upper] = true,
  [string.lower] = true,
  ... -- other authorized functions
}

local function hook (event)
  if event == "call" then
    local info = debug.getinfo(2, "fn")
    if not validfunc[info.func] then
      error("calling bad function: " .. (info.name or "?"))
    end
  end
  count = count + 1
  if count > steplimit then
    error("script uses too much CPU")
  end
end

local f = assert(loadfile(arg[1], "t", {}))  -- load chunk
debug.sethook(hook, "", 100)                 -- set hook
f()                                          -- run chunk
```

Right off the bat I am puzzled by this code, since the hook tests for event type (`if event == "call" then`...), and yet, when the hook is set, only count events are requested (`debug.sethook(hook, "", 100)`).  Therefore, the whole song-and-dance with `validfunc` is for naught.

Maybe it is a typo.  So I tried experimenting with this code, but I found it very difficult to put the whitelist technique in practice.  The example below is a *very simplified illustration* of the type of problems I ran into.

First, here is a slightly modified version of the author's code.

```
#!/usr/bin/env lua5.3
-- Filename: sandbox
-- ----------------------------------------------------------------------------
local debug = require "debug"

local steplimit = 1000    -- maximum "steps" that can be performed
local count = 0           -- counter for steps

local validfunc = {       -- set of authorized functions
  [string.upper] = true,
  [string.lower] = true,
  [io.stdout.write] = true,
  -- ...    -- other authorized functions
}

local function hook (event)
  if event == "call" then
    local info = debug.getinfo(2, "fnS")
    if not validfunc[info.func] then
      error(string.format("calling bad function (%s:%d): %s",
                          info.short_src, info.linedefined, (info.name or "?")))
    end
  end
  count = count + 1
  if count > steplimit then
    error("script uses too much CPU")
  end
end

local f = assert(loadfile(arg[1], "t", {}))     -- load chunk
validfunc[f] = true
debug.sethook(hook, "c", 100)                   -- set hook
f()                                             -- run chunk
```

The most significant differences in the second snippet relative to the first one are:

1. the call to `debug.sethook` has `"c"` as mask;
2. the `f` function for the loaded chunk gets added to the `validfunc` whitelist;
3. `io.stdout.write` is added to the `validfunc` whitelist;

When I use this `sandbox` program to run the one-line script shown below:

```
# Filename: helloworld.lua

io.stdout:write("Hello, World!\n")
```

...I get the following error:

```
% ./sandbox helloworld.lua
lua5.3: ./sandbox:20: calling bad function ([C]:-1): __index
stack traceback:
    [C]: in function 'error'
    ./sandbox:20: in function <./sandbox:16>
    [C]: in metamethod '__index'
    helloworld.lua:3: in local 'f'
    ./sandbox:34: in main chunk
    [C]: in ?
```

I tried to fix this by adding the following to `validfunc`:

```
  [getmetatable(io.stdout).__index] = true,
```

...but I still get pretty much the same error.  I could go on guessing and trying more things to add, but this is what I would like to avoid.

---

I have two related questions:

1. What can I add to `validfunc` so that `sandbox` will run `helloworld` (*as is*) to completion?
2. More importantly, what is a systematic way to find determine what to add to a whitelist table?

*Part (2) is the heart of this post.*  I am looking for tools/techniques that remove the guesswork from the problem of populating a whitelist table.

(I know that I can get `helloworld` to work if I replace `io.stdout:write` with `print`, register `print` in `sandbox`'s `validfunc`, and pass `{print = print}` as the last argument to `loadfile`, but doing this does not answer the *general* question of how to systematically determine what needs to be added to the whitelist to allow some *specific* code to work in the sandbox.)

---

**EDIT:** Ask @DarkWiiPlayer pointed out, the `calling bad function` error is being triggered by the calling of an unregistered function (`__index`?), which happened as part of the response to an earlier `attempt to index a nil value` error.  So, this post's questions are all about systematically determining what to add to `validfunc` to allow Lua to emit the `attempt to index a nil value` error normally.

I should add that the question of *which function's call* triggered the hook's execution responsible for the `calling bad function` error message is at the moment completely unclear.  This error message blames the error on `__index`, but I suspect that this may be a red herring, possibly due to a bug in Lua.

Why suspect a bug in Lua?  If I change the `error` call in `sandbox` slightly to

```
      error(string.format("calling bad function (%s:%d): %s (%s)",
                          info.short_src, info.linedefined, (info.name or "?"),
                          info.func))
```

...then the error message looks like this:

```
lua5.3: ./sandbox:20: calling bad function ([C]:-1): __index (function: 0x55b391b79ef0)
stack traceback:
    [C]: in function 'error'
    ./sandbox:20: in function <./sandbox:16>
    [C]: in metamethod '__index'
    helloworld.lua:3: in local 'f'
    ./sandbox:34: in main chunk
    [C]: in ?
```

Nothing surprising there, but if now I change `helloworld.lua` to

```
# Filename: helloworld.lua

nonexistent()
io.stdout:write("Hello, World!\n")
```

...and run it under `sandbox`, the error message becomes

```
lua5.3: ./sandbox:20: calling bad function ([C]:-1): nonexistent (function: 0x556a161cdef0)
stack traceback:
    [C]: in function 'error'
    ./sandbox:20: in function <./sandbox:16>
    [C]: in global 'nonexistent'
    helloworld.lua:3: in local 'f'
    ./sandbox:34: in main chunk
    [C]: in ?
```

From this error message, one may conclude that `nonexistent` is a real function; after all, it's sitting right there at `0x556a161cdef0`!  But we know that `nonexistent` lives up to its name: it doesn't exist!

The whiff of a bug is definitely in the air.  It could be that the function that is triggering the hook should really be excluded from those that trigger such `"c"`-masked hooks?  Be that as it may, it appears that, in this particular situation, the call to `debug.info` is returning inconsistent information (since the name of the function [e.g. `nonexistent`] clearly does not correspond at all to the actual function object [e.g. `function: 0x556a161cdef0`] that is supposedly triggering the hook).

Comment: I just came back to update my answer now that some time has passed and noticed that I can't reproduce the problem on this PC. Not sure why, but it actually prints an error message that makes sense for me, though I did manage to get your weird error before. Either way, that's just Lua being weird and the real problem lies somewhere else; see my answer for more details.

Answer (score 1):

(Final answer at the bottom, feel free to skip until the `<hr>` line)

I'll explain my debugging step by step.

This is a really weird phenomenon. After some testing, I've managed to narrow it down a bit:

- Since you pass `{}` to load, the function runs with an empty environment, so `io` is, in fact, nil (and `io.stdout` would error anyway)
- The error happens directly when attempting to index `io` (which is a nil value)
- The functio `__index` is a C function (see error message)

My first intuition was that `__index` was called somewhere internally. Thus, to find out what it does, I decided to look at its locals in hopes of guessing what it does.

A quick helper function I threw together:

```lua
local function locals(f)
   return function(f, n)
      local name, value = debug.getlocal(f+1, n)
      if name then
         return n+1, name, value
      end
   end, f, 1
end
```

Insert that right before the line where the error is raised:

```lua
      for idx, name, value in locals(2) do
         print(name, value)
      end
      error(string.format("calling bad function (%s:%d): %s", info.short_src, info.linedefined, (info.name or "?")))
```

This led to an interesting result:

```
(*temporary)    stdin:43: attempt to index a nil value (global 'io')
(*temporary)    table: 0x563cef2fd170
lua: stdin:29: calling bad function ([C]:-1): __index
stack traceback:
    [C]: in function 'error'
    stdin:29: in function <stdin:21>
    [C]: in metamethod '__index'
    stdin:43: in function 'f'
    stdin:49: in main chunk
    [C]: in ?

shell returned 1
```

Why is there a temporary string value with a completely different error message?

By the way, this error makes total sense; `io` does not exist because of the empty environment, so indexing it should *obviously* raise just that error.

It's honestly a very interesting error, but I'll leave it at this, as you're learning the language and this hint might be enough for you to figure it out on your own. It's also a very nice chance to actually use (and get to know) the `debug` module in a more practical context.

---

## Actual Solution

After some time has now passed, I came back to add a proper solution to this problem, but I really already did just that. The weird error reporting is just Lua being weird. The real error is the empty environment that's set when loading the chunk, as I mentioned a few paragraphs above.

From the manual:

> `load (chunk [, chunkname [, mode [, env]]])`
> Loads a chunk.
>
> [...]
>
> If the resulting function has upvalues, the first upvalue is set to the value of env, if that parameter is given, or to the value of the global environment. Other upvalues are initialized with nil. (When you load a main chunk, the resulting function will always have exactly one upvalue, the _ENV variable (see §2.2). However, when you load a binary chunk created from a function (see string.dump), the resulting function can have an arbitrary number of upvalues.) All upvalues are fresh, that is, they are not shared with any other function.
>
> [...]

Now, in a "main chunk", i.e. one loaded from a text Lua file, the first (and only) upvalue is always the environment of the chunk, so where it will look for "globals" (**this is slightly different in Lua 5.1**). Since an empty table is passed in, the chunk has no access to any of the global variables like `string` or `io`.

Therefore, when the function `f()` tries to index `io`, Lua throws an error "attempt to index a nil value", because `io` is nil. For whatever reason Lua then makes some internal function calls that end up triggering the blacklist, causing a new error that shadows the previous one; this makes debugging this error extremely inconvenient and almost impossible without using the `debug` library to get additional information about the call stack.

I ultimately only realized this myself after I noticed the original error message while looking at the locals of the function that made the blocked call.

## I hope this solves the problem :)

Comment: Thank you for this answer.  I figured out some of what you wrote in your addendum after I read your original answer.  Namely, that the hook is being triggered by a function that gets invoked in response to the "attempt to index a nil value" error.

Still I would like to know how to determine the function `__index` that the original error was complaining about (so that I can add it to `validfunc`).  I suspect, however, that this won't be possible using plain Lua.  One may need to run the Lua interpreter under gdb (or some such).

Comment: I've come to suspect a bug in Lua.  I have added info on this to my post.